# Does SQL Server ownership chaining not work for ALTER?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have a case where SQL Server ownership chaining doesn't seem to work - or am I missing something?

I have two schemas: `Schema1` and `Schema2`.

In `Schema1`, I only have `SELECT` permissions, while in `Schema2`, I only have `EXEC` permissions.

I call a stored procedure in `Schema2` which inserts a record into a table in `Schema1`.

This works fine (even though I don't have `INSERT` permissions in `Schema1`) due to ownership chaining.

Now, when I call another stored procedure which turns off the identity column in the table before inserting I get an error:

```
Msg 1088, Level 16, State 11, Procedure Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 60]
Cannot find the object "Schema1.MyTable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

If I grant `ALTER` permissions to `Schema1`, it works fine - but why is that necessary? Why doesn't schema chaining work in this case?

Script that reproduces the problem:

```
CREATE DATABASE OwnershipChainingTest
GO

USE OwnershipChainingTest
GO

CREATE SCHEMA Schema1 AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA Schema2 AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

CREATE TABLE Schema1.MyTable
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Title varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Schema2.AddRecord
    @title nvarchar(100) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Schema1.MyTable (Title) 
    VALUES (@title)
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId
    @id int,
    @title nvarchar(100) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema1.MyTable ON

    INSERT INTO Schema1.MyTable (Id, Title) 
    VALUES (@id, @title)

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT Schema1.MyTable OFF
END
GO

CREATE USER MyUser WITHOUT LOGIN
GO

CREATE ROLE MyRole AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember MyRole, MyUser
GO

-- With this it works: GRANT SELECT, ALTER ON Schema::Schema1 TO MyRole
GRANT SELECT ON Schema::Schema1 TO MyRole
GO
GRANT EXEC ON Schema::Schema2 TO MyRole
GO

EXEC AS user = 'MyUser'

EXEC Schema2.AddRecord 'hello1'
GO

-- This causes an error
EXEC Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId 42, 'hello2'
GO

REVERT;
--SELECT CURRENT_USER

SELECT * FROM Schema1.MyTable

USE MASTER
DROP DATABASE OwnershipChainingTest
GO
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Msg 1088, Level 16, State 11, Procedure Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 60]
Cannot find the object "Schema1.MyTable" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: @ThomasBoelSigurdsson, I answered your question but be sure to consider the concurrency implications if different users execute the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` proc at the same time.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you. That is also what I thought/feared - I just could not find it described anywhere. It is a good point with the concurrency implications. I do, however, have a need to be able to specify an id once in a while even though in general ids will be drawn from the identity column. Is there a way of drawing an id from a sequence that is external to the table? E.g. can you have something like an identify column that you can draw a value from on an adhoc basis?

Comment: @ThomasBoelSigurdsson, I think a [`SEQUENCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is more appropriate than `IDENTITY`  for occasional ad-hoc values. `CREATE SEQUENCE Schema1.MyTable_Sequence AS bigint START WITH 1;CREATE TABLE Schema1.MyTable (Id int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MyTable_Sequence DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR Schema1.MyTable_Sequence,...`

Comment: So the next sequence value will be assigned automatically when the column is not specified (similarly to IDENTITY) but can be overridden in normal DML as desired. But if you need to immediately get the value assigned by the default constraint (like `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`), you'll need to use an OUTPUT clause. Or, instead of a default constraint, you could assign next sequence value to a local variable in the proc and specify that for the value.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman - that is just what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ownership chaining applies only to DML. `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is essentially a DDL operation, which is why it requires at least `ALTER` permissions on the table.

A good way to allow minimally privileged users with only execute permissions to run the proc is by signing the proc with a certificate based on a user with `ALTER` permissions:

```
--create certificate and sign proc
CREATE CERTIFICATE AddRecordWithSpecificIdCert
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'temporary password'
   WITH SUBJECT = 'Allow ALTER on Schema1';
ADD SIGNATURE TO  Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId BY CERTIFICATE AddRecordWithSpecificIdCert WITH PASSWORD = 'temporary password';

--remove ephemeral private key
ALTER CERTIFICATE AddRecordWithSpecificIdCert REMOVE PRIVATE KEY;

--create a user from certificate with the needed permissions
CREATE USER AddRecordWithSpecificIdCertUser FROM CERTIFICATE AddRecordWithSpecificIdCert;
GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::Schema1 TO AddRecordWithSpecificIdCertUser;
GO

--this test now works
EXEC AS user = 'MyUser';
GO
EXEC Schema2.AddRecordWithSpecificId 42, 'hello2'
GO
REVERT;
GO
```

Comment: Why remove the private key on the cert? If/when this proc gets changed, it will need to be resigned and removing the private key means that you'll have to create a new cert, a new user from the cert, grant permissions to that user, and then finally sign the proc again.

Comment: @BenThul, although not required, I generally use an ephemeral certificate and user for each signed module and recreate them each time the object is recreated or altered. I've found this simplifies management of certs and secrets, keeping the permissions script under source control along with the proc. I also have a utility proc to facilitate, with parameters for the proc name and permission script. The proc generates and executes the signing script during deployments, using naming conventions like the example in my answer.